# Hyperledger fabric v1 network of physical layers

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

How to setup hyperledger fabric v1 network on physical peers instead of docker peers?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment
It deploys automatically to linux virtual machines / physical hosts:

- A few peers, according to your configuration
- A solo orderer
- Everything with TLS
- Creates a channel and installs and invokes example02 chaincode for sanity testing

Answer (score -1):

The docker containers provide a mechanism to take care of a lot of configs that happens behind the curtain, and that is the preferred way. If you choose to use fabric directly over a server without Docker, one way would be to build the binaries yourself via the `make` command and take a look at the 1) shell script in getting started and the 2) Docker-compose file (in http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) to deconstruct  the steps and configs, but this will be a pretty involved process.